# CREATE PROCEDURE error in SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a login and registration form in ASP.net and I came across one page out of a million that looked like it could help me. Problem is when I follow the steps, I seem to get a error, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong or maybe if the guy who wrote the steps are wrong?

Steps I'm following:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rohatash/simple-user-login-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp/

What I did:

I opened SQL Server Management Studio, created a database called `VC_temps`, right clicked, selected new query and typed the following code

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
StudCode        varchar(10),
FirstName       varchar(30),
LastNmae        varchar(30),
Telephone       char(10),
Course          varchar(30),
Pword           varchar(20),
Availability    varchar(50),
JobSkill        varchar(50),
Experience      varchar(50)
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[VC-Temps]
(
@StudCode       varchar(10),
@FirstName      varchar(30),
@LastNmae       varchar(30),
@Telephone      char(10),
@Course         varchar(30),
@Pword          varchar(20),
@Availability   varchar(50),
@JobSkill       varchar(50),
@Experience     varchar(50)
)
AS
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (@StudCode, @FirstName, @LastNmae, @Telephone, @Course, @Pword,     @Availability, @JobSkill, @Experience)
```

The error I'm receiving seems to be at

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[VC-Temps]
```

Error is:

> *Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure VC-Temps, Line 27
>
>   'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE PROCEDURE` blocks, insert `GO`, to cause SQL server to execute.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
StudCode        varchar(10),
FirstName       varchar(30),
LastNmae        varchar(30),
Telephone       char(10),
Course          varchar(30),
Pword           varchar(20),
Availability    varchar(50),
JobSkill        varchar(50),
Experience      varchar(50)
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[VC-Temps]
(
@StudCode       varchar(10),
@FirstName      varchar(30),
@LastNmae       varchar(30),
@Telephone      char(10),
@Course         varchar(30),
@Pword          varchar(20),
@Availability   varchar(50),
@JobSkill       varchar(50),
@Experience     varchar(50)
)
AS
    INSERT INTO Student VALUES (@StudCode, @FirstName, @LastNmae, @Telephone, @Course,     @Pword,     @Availability, @JobSkill, @Experience)
```